# Get information about specific user tweets. Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

How to get information about specific user tweets, using Twitter API? 
Actually, I need watching by this user and then new tweet is appears I need to be informed about that. 
I am using Node.js and Twitter API.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at twitter's [API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users)?

Comment: Yes, but still have no idea how to do that? I will be very appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GET statuses/user_timeline` API to fetch a single user's tweets.
Follow [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var T = new Twitter({
  consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token_key:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})

var options = { screen_name: 'or user_id',
               count: 1 };

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', options , function(err, data) {
     //code for notification.
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
But at code one mistake: 
  access_token_key: